# AWS Lambda custom triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can someone tell me how to get access to AWS credentials in an AWS Lambda function?

I've searched the internet thoroughly but still haven't found anything that has helped me.

Im writing the function in Java. I think I should have access to the credentials with the context object in the `HandleRequest` method.

If it helps, I want to invoke a DynamoDB client and upload a record to the database.

Comment: why don't you give a try directly without looking for any credentials? you are running on AWS already therefore it should infer the ones you used to connect lambda, so it should work

Comment: You mean just calling. DynamoDbClient client = new dynamoDbClient(); and then the normal stuff. Really, is it that easy? Can you confirm this?

Comment: As far as I now that should work, but  haven't tried that in the past

Comment: BTW, I found this other scenario where you  receive the records from DynamoDB triggers, maybe this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789078/aws-dynamodb-trigger-using-lambda-in-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came into the same problem myself recently. 
This certainly is a blind spot in AWS's Lambda documentation for Java, in my opinion.

This snippet in Java should work for you, assuming you're using the AWS SDK for Java Document API :

```
DynamoDB dynamodb = new DynamoDB(
    new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()));
```

The main takeaway is to use the EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider to access the required credentials to access your other AWS resources within the AWS Lambda container. The Lambda containers are shipped with credentials as environment variables, and this is sufficient in retrieving them.

Note: This creates a DynamoDB instance that only sees resources in the default region. To create one for a specific region, use this (assuming you want to access DynamoDB's in the ap-northeast-1 region):

```
DynamoDB dynamodb = new DynamoDB(
    Regions.getRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1).createClient(
        AmazonDynamoDBClient.class,
        new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(),
        new ClientConfiguration()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Lambda function's permissions are controlled by the IAM Role it executes as.  Either add Dynamo PutItem permission to the current role, or create a new role for this purpose.

[image]

After giving permissions to the Role, you don't need to write special code to handle credentials, just use the AWS SDK normally.  For example:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    var putItemParams = {
        "TableName": "Scratch",
        "Item": {
            "Id": {
                "S": "foo"
            },
            "Text": {
                "S": "bar"
            }
        }
    };
    dynamodb.putItem(putItemParams, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            context.fail("dynamodb.putItem failed: " + err);
        } else {
            context.succeed("dynamodb.putItem succeeded");
        }
    });
};
```

Is sufficient to put an item in a DynamoDB table, with the correct Role permissions.

Comment: I'd recommend using https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk instead of `aws-sdk` for `DynamoDB` connections.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Gordon Tai's answer, using the current api using AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder this looks like:

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
  .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
  .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
  .build();
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
```