# AWS Lambda function extremely slow to retrieve S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that needs to read a file from S3 every time it is executed.
The file is very small, about 200 bytes, the S3 bucket is in the US Standard region, the Lambda function is in the us-east-1 region (so the same region). It takes between 10 and 15 seconds to read the file, how come this is so slow?

Thanks.

EDIT: some code

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
S3Object propertyFile = null;
try {
    propertyFile = s3Client.getObject(S3_BUCKET_NAME, S3_PROPERTY_FILE);
} catch (Exception e) {...}
try (InputStream in = propertyFile.getObjectContent()) {
    PROPERTIES.load(in);
} catch (Exception e) {...}
LOGGER.debug("S3 access " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
```

EDIT #2: After Brooks' suggestion I did

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider());
```

And I get this error:

```
Unable to load credentials from Amazon EC2 metadata service
```

EDIT #3:
The memory allocated to the Lambda function was 256MB, when I allocate 1024MB, it takes 3-4 seconds which is still too slow (it takes about 1-2 seconds when I test locally from my computer).

Comment: The person who down voted could maybe explain the reason.

Comment: Try specifying the InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider when instantiating the AmazonS3Client.  The default constructor needs to attempt authorization via (in this order) environment variables, system properties, credentials file and then instance profile.  So, your preferred authorization method is last.  I wouldn't think it would take THAT long, however give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken.  I had thought that Lambda containers shipped with InstanceProfiles (I can't figure out why it wouldn't).  It seems it ships with credentials specified in environment variables (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275169/aws-lambda-custom-triggers).  Try specifying (new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()) when instantiating the AmazonS3Client.  Even though it's the first item in the list of credentials checked when using the default constructor, it can't hurt to try.  Let us know.

Comment: Stilll about 12 seconds to read the file...

Comment: Then I would have to echo eistrati and unfortunately suggest you send an email to AWS or post to the AWS forum.  If you want to continue troubleshooting, put this code onto an EC2 instance and see what happens, though that won't actually help you solve the problem on Lambda.

Comment: Maybe try specifiying the region when setting up the s3 client? Although it's hard to see why that would shave off 12 seconds...

Comment: The thing is US_Standard is the default region http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/Region.html

Comment: You should try and update the s3-client lib version. It solves many problems for me. You can also attach an observer to the S3Client object and get the buffering precentage/state during the download, it might help

Comment: @MaximeLaval any luck with this . I am too facing same problem with my django app deployed on aws Lambda and staticfiles on s3. it is very slow

Comment: @ManujRastogi Actually I gave up, in my case they are property files so I ended up passing stage variables from API Gateway. But I assume there are many cases where people really need to access any kind of files hosted on S3 directly from a Lambda function. I'll let you know when I try again.

Comment: I have the same issue where my Java Lambda just creates an S3 client and then performs a `putObject`. When running with 256MB I timed it and the breakdown is usually close to this: 7.5s to create the S3 client, 7.5s to put the object. =/ I wonder if there is some JITting going on since the first call takes about 15s, the second call takes about 2 seconds (about 30% client creation / 70% putObject), and subsequent calls are about 1s (10% client creation / 90% putObject).

Answer (score 4):

What I would suggest is to use `ProfileCredentialsProvider` and to cache S3 client instance between Lambda function executions:

```
public class MyLambda { // No matter you implement standard AWS SDK interfaces or not

    private final AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());

    public String sayHello(Request request, Context context) {
        S3Object s3Obj = s3Client.getObject(request.getBucket(), request.getKey());
        return S3Utils.getContent(s3Object); // Some util which retrieves object content
    }
}
```

The thing is that it takes some time to set up the S3 client which manages connections pool and other resources.

Comment: `ProfileCredentialsProvider ` works with the role permissions you've assigned to your function.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who still comes across this problem, I just fixed it by increasing the lambda memory.  My lambda at 128MB was taking 10 seconds to get the contents of a 2K text file from S3.  I increased the memory to 256 MB and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Same issue here. I did a quick test with some values for memory: 
`128 MB - 15s`, `256 MB - 6s`, `512 MB - 3.5s`, `1024 MB - 1.5s`, `2048 MB - 1.1s`. 
Quite strange behaviour since max memory used is ~85 MB according to the logs.

Comment: I think it is because "The amount of memory also determines the amount of virtual CPU available to a function".  See: "Memory and computing power" in AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/computing-power.html

Comment: The problem seems also related the something else. E.g in a new account with only a few S3 buckets, the s3-client init time is ~1s. In an old account with a lot of resources; buckets, objects etc, the init time is 30s. Both with 128MB.

Comment: @selle did you get any workaround for this at that time ?

Comment: @umeshWeb Not yet apart from increasing memory. But in order to save cost, I cache the s3-client so that the consecutively s3 interactions is at least faster. I use python and cachetools.func.ttl_cache. Please share any findings