# Java DynamoDB Streams Lambda: "Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from Floating-point value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT`)"

Tags: json, aws-lambda, jackson, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm writing an AWS Lambda that will listen for DynamoDB Streams events and use those events to update an Elasticsearch index.  My code is written using the Quarkus framework, and I've found [guides and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789078/aws-dynamodb-trigger-using-lambda-in-java) that show how to do this, so my code looks like this:

```
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent;

/**
 * The AWS Lambda used to update an Elasticsearch index when new records are
 * written to DynamoDB
 * 
 * @author XXX
 *
 */
@Named("dynamoDBSearchIndexEventHandler")
public class DynamoDBSearchIndexEventHandler implements RequestHandler<DynamodbEvent, Void> {

    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamoDBSearchIndexEventHandler.class);

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see
     * com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler#handleRequest(java.lang.
     * Object, com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context)
     */
    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(DynamodbEvent input, Context context) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("handleRequest(DynamodbEvent, Context) - start"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("handleRequest(DynamodbEvent, Context) - input={}", input); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("handleRequest(DynamodbEvent, Context) - end"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I write an item to my DynamoDB table I see that my Lambda is being called, however I get the following Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from Floating-point value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT`)
```

I have no idea why serialization is failing.  If I modify my Lambda to take `Map<String, AttributeValue>` as the input instead of `DynamodbEvent` it works just fine.  I'm able to see the `Map` populated with all of the expected values.  However, I cannot get a `DynamodbEvent` that I can then subsequently use to iterate over its `DynamodbStreamRecord` objects for updating my index.

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14513) with Quarkus.  I used the `ObjectMapperCustomizer` provided in the issue record and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently have issues with the Java Lambda's and deserializing data.  At this point I've given up and just use JsonPath:

```
public class S3EventLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {

        try {
            List<String> keys = JsonPath.read(inputStream, "$.Records[*].s3.object.key");

            for( String nextKey: keys )
                System.out.println(nextKey);
        }
        catch( IOException ioe ) {
            context.getLogger().log("caught IOException reading input stream");
        }
    }
```

This is handling [an S3 event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) but the concepts should be the same.